# Can I set state inside a useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Lets say I have some state that is dependent on some other state (eg when A changes I want B to change).

Is it appropriate to create a hook that observes A and sets B inside the useEffect hook?

Will the effects cascade such that, when I click the button, the first effect will fire, causing b to change, causing the second effect to fire, before the next render? Are there any performance downsides to structuring code like this?

```
let MyComponent = props => {
  let [a, setA] = useState(1)
  let [b, setB] = useState(2)
  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (/*some stuff is true*/) {
        setB(3)
      }
    },
    [a],
  )
  useEffect(
    () => {
      // do some stuff
    },
    [b],
  )

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setA(5)
      }}
    >
      click me
    </button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Effects are always executed after the render phase is completed even if you setState inside the one effect, another effect will read the updated state and take action on it only after the render phase.

Having said that its probably better to take both actions in the same effect unless there is a possibility that `b` can change due to reasons other than `changing a` in which case too you would want to execute the same logic

Comment: So if A changes B, the component would render twice right?

Comment: @alaboudi Yes, if A changes causing useeffect to run which sets B then the component does render twice

Comment: @alaboudi Yes.. as Shubham Khatri  said it will render again.
but you can skip calling your effect after the re-rendering using the second argument refer https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Answer (score 240):

Generally speaking, using `setState` inside `useEffect` will create an infinite loop that most likely you don't want to cause. There are a couple of exceptions to that rule which I will get into later.

`useEffect` is called after each render and when `setState` is used inside of it, it will cause the component to re-render which will call `useEffect` and so on and so on.

One of the popular cases that using `useState` inside of `useEffect` will not cause an infinite loop is when you pass an empty array as a second argument to `useEffect` like `useEffect(() => {....}, [])` which means that the effect function should be called once: after the first mount/render only. This is used widely when you're doing data fetching in a component and you want to save the request data in the component's state.

Comment: Another case to use `setState` inside `useEffect` is `setting state` inside subscription or event listeners. But don't forget to cancel the subscription  https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup

Comment: This is not strictly true - useState only fires if the the value you are updating the state with is different to the previous one so an infinite loop is prevented unless the value changes between cycles.

Comment: This answer is incorrect and not to the point of the question: in the code in case, the component renders only twice when the button is clicked, there's no infinite loop

Comment: It's a very common use case to set state inside useEffect.  Think about data loading, useEffect calls API, gets data, sets using set part of useState.

Comment: The first paragraph of this answer states unconditionally that this should not be done, but this is very commonly done. Maybe rearrange to make the condition you add in the third paragraph more prominent.

Comment: I updated the answer to address the issues you mentioned, is it better now?

Comment: It's worth noting the React team now specifically tells you to do state updates (when component A sets a state using a setter provided by component B) inside a `useEffect` hook, and if you don't you'll get a warning in the latest version of React.

Comment: @machineghost Can you find a link to where the React team says that?

Comment: When I tried to set state in the component body, I got an error message (from React).  When I saw that message (nearly a year ago) I *think* it linked to a page, but I don't have the URL handy unfortunately.  But really, it just comes down to understanding React: if you set state inside a component's function, it could trigger an infinite loop, because state changes trigger re-renders, so ... you set state, it re-renders, it sets the state again, re-renders again ... `useEffect` avoids this by only running the state-setter when the component is first mounted.

Comment: When I try to update state in my `useEffect`, the state variable is not updated. Based on other comments, my call looks like this `setSizeGuideData(sizeGuideData => ({ ...sizeGuideData, getFilteredSizeGuide }));` When I log `sizeGuideData`, I get `[]` returned. `getFilteredSizeGuide` has the correct data. So no idea why it's not working.

Comment: @HossamMourad Since the question clearly has specified dependency array for the `useEffect(callback, [a])`, I think you could update your answer to include the point where useEffect runs **ONCE** after initial rendering and after every rendering **ONLY IF** the dependencies change, `a` and `b` as is in the question.

Answer (score 176):

For future purposes, this may help too:

It's ok to use setState in `useEffect` you just need to have attention as described already to not create a loop.

**But it's not the only problem that may occur. See below:**

Imagine that you have a component `Comp` that receives `props` from parent and according to a `props` change you want to set `Comp`'s state. For some reason, you need to change for each prop in a different `useEffect`:

**DO NOT DO THIS**

```
useEffect(() => {
  setState({ ...state, a: props.a });
}, [props.a]);

useEffect(() => {
  setState({ ...state, b: props.b });
}, [props.b]);
```

It may never change the state of a as you can see in this example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-lederberg-dtx7w

The reason why this happen in this example it's because **both useEffects run in the same react cycle** when you change both `prop.a` and `prop.b` so the value of `{...state}` when you do `setState` are exactly the same in both `useEffect` because they are in the same context. When you run the second `setState` it will replace the first `setState`.

**DO THIS INSTEAD**

The solution for this problem is basically call `setState` like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setState(state => ({ ...state, a: props.a }));
}, [props.a]);

useEffect(() => {
  setState(state => ({ ...state, b: props.b }));
}, [props.b]);
```

Check the solution here: https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-surf-nynlx

Now, you always receive the most updated and correct value of the state when you proceed with the `setState`.

Comment: above solution helped me `setName(name => ({ ...name, a: props.a }));`

Comment: this helped me as well in the part with the arrow function `setItems(items => [...items, item])`

Comment: Spent 7 AM to 3 PM without having a solution and now you saved me.

Comment: I tried this solution. `setState(state => ({ ...state, useEffectValue }));` When I log `state`, it remains empty. If I pass `useEffectValue` in the output array, I get an infinite loop. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: can't thank you enough for this incredible tip. I was indeed overriding the state from multiple useEffect calls that were triggering all when mounting the component.

Comment: The above solution works. Directly trying change the state didn't help. However, passing in an updater function did the trick. reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html

Comment: I had exact same issue. I stacked without any idea what happening thanks for greate explanation.

Comment: Should probably be a linting rule

Answer (score 38):

`useEffect` can hook on a certain prop or state. so, the thing you need to do to avoid infinite loop hook is binding some variable or state to effect

For Example:

```
useEffect(myeffectCallback, [])
```

above effect will fire only once the component has rendered. this is similar to `componentDidMount` lifecycle

```
const [something, setSomething] = withState(0)
const [myState, setMyState] = withState(0)
useEffect(() => {
  setSomething(0)
}, myState)
```

above effect will fire only my state has changed this is similar to `componentDidUpdate` except not every changing state will fire it.

You can read more detail though this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

Comment: Thank you, this answer addresses the dependency array of useEffect in a way other answer did not. Including an empty array as a second argument to useEffect will make sure useEffect executes once the component has rendered, but including an array with a specific state or specific states will cause the useEffect to execute when the states in reference have changed.

Comment: I don't understand what `withState()` represents. I can't find any reference to it in the doc.

Comment: I think that should be `useState(0)`.

Answer (score 31):

▶ 1. Can I set state inside a useEffect hook?

In principle, you can set state freely where you need it - including inside `useEffect` and [even during rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-getderivedstatefromprops). Just make sure to avoid infinite loops by settting Hook `deps` properly and/or state conditionally.

---

▶ 2. Lets say I have some state that is dependent on some other state. Is it appropriate to create a hook that observes A and sets B inside the useEffect hook?

You just described *the* classic use case for [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer):

> `useReducer` is usually preferable to `useState` when you have **complex state** logic that involves **multiple sub-values** or when the next state depends on the previous one. ([React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer))
>
> When setting a **state** variable **depends on** the current value of **another state** variable, you might want to try replacing them both with `useReducer`.
>   [...] When you find yourself [writing](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) `setSomething(something => ...)`, it’s a good time to consider using a reducer instead. ([Dan Abramov, Overreacted blog](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#decoupling-updates-from-actions))

```js
let MyComponent = () => {
  let [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { a: 1, b: 2 });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Some effect with B");
  }, [state.b]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>A: {state.a}, B: {state.b}</p>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "SET_A", payload: 5 })}>
        Set A to 5 and Check B
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT_B" })}>
        Increment B
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

// B depends on A. If B >= A, then reset B to 1.
function reducer(state, { type, payload }) {
  const someCondition = state.b >= state.a;

  if (type === "SET_A")
    return someCondition ? { a: payload, b: 1 } : { ...state, a: payload };
  else if (type === "INCREMENT_B") return { ...state, b: state.b + 1 };
  return state;
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-32Gmw5rBDXyMjg/73FgpukoTZdMrxuYW7tj8adbN8z4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-bjQ42ac3EN0GqK40pC9gGi/YixvKyZ24qMP/9HiGW7w=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script>var { useReducer, useEffect } = React</script>
```

---

▶ 3. Will the effects cascade such that, when I click the button, the first effect will fire, causing b to change, causing the second effect to fire, before the next render?

`useEffect` always runs *after* the render is committed and DOM changes are applied. The first effect fires, changes `b` and causes a re-render. After this render has completed, second effect will run due to `b` changes.

```js
let MyComponent = props => {
  console.log("render");
  let [a, setA] = useState(1);
  let [b, setB] = useState(2);

  let isFirstRender = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect a, value:", a);
    if (isFirstRender.current) isFirstRender.current = false;
    else setB(3);
    return () => {
      console.log("unmount useEffect a, value:", a);
    };
  }, [a]);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect b, value:", b);
    return () => {
      console.log("unmount useEffect b, value:", b);
    };
  }, [b]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>a: {a}, b: {b}</p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log("Clicked!");
          setA(5);
        }}
      >
        click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-32Gmw5rBDXyMjg/73FgpukoTZdMrxuYW7tj8adbN8z4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-bjQ42ac3EN0GqK40pC9gGi/YixvKyZ24qMP/9HiGW7w=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script>var { useReducer, useEffect, useState, useRef } = React</script>
```

---

▶ 4. Are there any performance downsides to structuring code like this?

Yes. By wrapping the state change of `b` in a separate `useEffect` for `a`, the browser has an additional layout/paint phase - these effects are potentially visible for the user. If there is no way you want give `useReducer` a try, you could change `b` state together with `a` directly:

```js
let MyComponent = () => {
  console.log("render");
  let [a, setA] = useState(1);
  let [b, setB] = useState(2);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect b, value:", b);
    return () => {
      console.log("unmount useEffect b, value:", b);
    };
  }, [b]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("Clicked!");
    setA(5);
    b >= 5 ? setB(1) : setB(b + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        a: {a}, b: {b}
      </p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-32Gmw5rBDXyMjg/73FgpukoTZdMrxuYW7tj8adbN8z4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-bjQ42ac3EN0GqK40pC9gGi/YixvKyZ24qMP/9HiGW7w=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script>var { useReducer, useEffect, useState, useRef } = React</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try wrapping the **setState** inside an if-statement that checks whether the state needs to be changed - if yes, change it, else `return () => {}`

e.g.,

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(a.currentCondition !== a.desiredCondition) {
        setA();
    }
    return cleanup;
}, [b])
```