# Having issues while converting one piece code of code to jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, g2plot

I am new to react. So please pardon my naiveness. I have the following piece of react code:

```
import { Line } from '@antv/g2plot';

const data = [
  { year: '1991', value: 3 },
  { year: '1992', value: 4 },
  { year: '1993', value: 3.5 },
  { year: '1994', value: 5 },
  { year: '1995', value: 4.9 },
  { year: '1996', value: 6 },
  { year: '1997', value: 7 },
  { year: '1998', value: 9 },
  { year: '1999', value: 13 },
];

const linePlot = new Line(document.getElementById('container'), {
  title: {
    visible: true,
    text: 'DEF',
  },
  description: {
    visible: true,
    text: 'ABC',
  },
  padding: 'auto',
  forceFit: true,
  data,
  xField: 'year',
  yField: 'value',
  smooth: true,
});

linePlot.render();
```

I need to convert the above piece of code inside a class and export it: I wrote the below code

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Line } from "
@antv
/g2plot";
export const YourComponentName = function() {
const [linePlot, setlinePlot] = useState(initialState);
const data = [
{ year: "1991", value: 3 },
{ year: "1992", value: 4 },
{ year: "1993", value: 3.5 },
{ year: "1994", value: 5 },
{ year: "1995", value: 4.9 },
{ year: "1996", value: 6 },
{ year: "1997", value: 7 },
{ year: "1998", value: 9 },
{ year: "1999", value: 13 }
];
useEffect(() => {
setlinePlot(
new Line(document.getElementById("container"), {
title: {
visible: true,
text: "DEF"
},
description: {
visible: true,
text: "ABC"
},
padding: "auto",
forceFit: true,
data,
xField: "year",
yField: "value",
smooth: true
})
);
return () => {
// you can clanup here
};
}, [linePlot]);
return; //jsx from here with state which you want to render.
};
```

However since, this is a container class, I don't want "document..getElementById("container")" in my this component class. My index.js already has

```
ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Please help me.

Comment: Could you explain what you want to be different?

Comment: @Jakub I want the code, written in the first section, to be converted to a component class

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from other react community platform. Am pasting it here, if someone faces a similar issue:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";

import { Line } from "@antv/g2plot";
import ReactG2Plot from "react-g2plot";


class SampleReact extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const data = [
        { year: "1991", value: 3 },
        { year: "1992", value: 4 },
        { year: "1993", value: 3.5 },
        { year: "1994", value: 5 },
        { year: "1995", value: 4.9 },
        { year: "1996", value: 6 },
        { year: "1997", value: 7 },
        { year: "1998", value: 9 },
        { year: "1999", value: 13 }
      ];
      const config = {
        title: {
          visible: true,
          text: "曲线折线图"
        },
        description: {
          visible: true,
          text: "用平滑的曲线代替折线。"
        },
        padding: "auto",
        forceFit: true,
        data,
        xField: "year",
        yField: "value",
        smooth: true
      };
    return (
        <ReactG2Plot Ctor={Line} config={config} />

    );
  }
}
export default SampleReact;
```

Answer (score 0):

In React you can either have a functional component or a class based component.
You have used the react `useState` and `useEffect` hooks, which are for functional components only and cannot be used in the class-based approach.

Just a side note. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54923969/10377254) talks about the reasons why you should not update state inside the useEffect hook.

Do you want the Line to be created once, when the component loads?

Another note. The 'below code' you mentioned does not use class's.

*Edit 
[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-monad-fml78) is a basic react implementation, however, due to you using antv/g2plot.Line I can't get it to update the graph without overlaying it on top of the old one. From a quick look at the docs, I would recommend changing it to a Chart.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can you please help write the component class for the first section of code?

Comment: Do you want to be able to change the data and the displayed graph will update?
I can try to get a basic implementation going, however, am unsure what your overall goal of moving it to a react component is.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob, for being kind enough to help me. I have got the answer from other react community. Thanks anyways.