# How to add DOM elements to my state, with useEffect hook without error/warning in the console?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm actually trying to target some DOM elements in my empty state with **useState** and **useEffect hooks**. 
No problem at all, I think I'm doing right. Here's my actual code :

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    title: [],
    subtitle: []
});

useEffect(() => {
    const myNewTitle = ["Hello", "World"];
    const myNewSubtitle = ["What's", "up?"];

    setState({...state, title: myNewTitle, subtitle: myNewSubtitle})
    console.log(state)
}, [state]);
```

Here, my console displays an infinite loop. 
I tried to write an empty array `[]`, but the new values of my state are not displaying in the console, like I would like to. 
So, I wrote this :
`[state.title[0], state.subtitle[0]]);` 
I don't know if my code is correct or not. The console displays what I wanted, the new values of my state. 
But I got this warning in my console :

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'state'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'setState(s => ...)' if you only need 'state' in the 'setState' call react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Actually, I don't know how to fix this issue. Can someone help me, please ?

**Precisions** : Of course, this is a really easy example. In my project, I want to re-use my state (title+subtitle) in functions wrote **outside of the useEffect hook**.

Comment: Take a look at this. It is not advised to use setState inside of useEffect because you can get an infinite loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715465/can-i-set-state-inside-a-useeffect-hook

Comment: Could you be mixing up setState (pre-hook state management) with useState (state changes with hooks)? Both can be used to achieve the same thing, hooks (useState, useEffect) are the new way to do it

Comment: You can definitely use `setState` inside `useEffect` but you're going to get an infinite loop if there's not a conditional set, or you pass an empty array for the dependencies, as referenced by @van answer below. Also, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54923969/6395983) on the same page referenced above.

Comment: Hey @displacedtexan, thanks for the post mention ! I tried the empty array, like I wrote in my post. But the console does not display the new content of my state. So, I'm pretty lost with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid having to put `state` in the dependency list by using the callback version of `setState()` which has the current state as a parameter.

Since that parameter is local (inside) the useEffect, it's not necessary to declare it as a dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {

  const myNewTitle = ["Hello", "World"];
  const myNewSubtitle = ["What's", "up?"];

  setState(oldState => {
    return {...oldState, title: myNewTitle, subtitle: myNewSubtitle};
  });

}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//can be anything, a string, undefined, a boolean
const [title, setTitle] = ("");
const [subtitle, setSubtitle] = ("");

//when the component is (re)rendered, this will be called.
useEffect(() => {

},[])
//"keeping track" of anything in the array, when they are updated, useEffect is executed
```

then in your component, you can call `setSubtitle("the value you want to update it with")`