# State is not updated properly when using React effects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a small todo app as an exercise using React. I have a mock service like this:

```
export default class TodoService {

    constructor(todos) {
        this.todos = new Map();
        todos.forEach(todo => {
            this.todos.set(todo.id, todo);
        });
    }

    findAll() {
        return Array.from(this.todos.values());
    }

    saveTodo(todo) {
        this.todos[todo.id] = todo
    }

    completeTodo(todo) {
        this.todos.delete(todo.id)
    }
}
```

and in my React app I have some state which contains the todos:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
const [flip, flipper] = useState(true);

const completeTodo = (todo) => {
    todoService.completeTodo(todo);
    flipper(!flip);
}

useEffect(() => {
    setTodos(todoService.findAll());
}, [flip])
```

`completeTodo` is a function which I pass into my `Todo` component to be used when I want to complete a todo like this:

```
import React from "react";
const Todo = ({ todo, completeFn }) => {
    return (
        <form className="todo">
            <div className="form-check">
                <input
                    className="form-check-input"
                    type="checkbox"
                    value=""
                    name={todo.id}
                    id={todo.id}
                    onClick={() => {
                        console.log(`completing todo...`)
                        completeFn(todo)
                    }} />
                <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor={todo.id}>
                    {todo.description}
                </label>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}
export default Todo
```

So what happens is that whenever the user clicks the checkbox `completeFn` is called with the `todo`, it gets deleted from the service object and the state is supposed to update, but the weirdest thing happens.

When `TodoService.completeTodo()` is called the todo gets deleted properly, but when `findAll()` is called the old todo is still there! If I write the contents to the console I can see the item being deleted then somehow teleported back when I call `findAll`. Why does this happen? I this because of some React magic I don't understand?

**Edit:** What's even more insane is that if I modify this to only use effects for the initial loading like this:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

const completeTodo = (todo) => {
    todoService.completeTodo(todo);
    setTodos(todoService.findAll());
}

useEffect(() => {
    setTodos(todoService.findAll());
}, [])
```

I get a *super weird* result:

[image]

Can someone explain this to me?

**Edit2:** This is a complete reproducible example (without the `index.html` with a `<div id="root"></div>` in it).

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Todo = ({ todo, completeFn }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                name={todo.id}
                id={todo.id}
                onClick={() => {
                    console.log(`completing todo...`)
                    completeFn(todo)
                }} />
            <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor={todo.id}>
                {todo.description}
            </label>
        </div>
    )
}

class TodoService {

    constructor(todos) {
        this.todos = new Map();
        todos.forEach(todo => {
            this.todos.set(todo.id, todo);
        });
    }

    findAll() {
        return Array.from(this.todos.values());
    }

    saveTodo(todo) {
        this.todos[todo.id] = todo
    }

    completeTodo(todo) {
        this.todos.delete(todo.id)
    }
}

const App = () => {

    let todoService = new TodoService([{
        id: 1,
        description: "Let's go home."
    }, {
        id: 2,
        description: "Take down the trash"
    }, {
        id: 3,
        description: "Play games"
    }]);

    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
    const [flip, flipper] = useState(true);

    const completeTodo = (todo) => {
        todoService.completeTodo(todo);
        flipper(!flip);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setTodos(todoService.findAll());
    }, [flip])

    return (
        <div>
            {todos.map(todo => <Todo key={todo.id} todo={todo} completeFn={completeTodo} />)}
        </div>
    )
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Yep, I just did.

Comment: I think the issue here is basically that you're trying to create a state object which exists outside the React render loop. When `flipper` gets called, the component is rerendered, and a new instance of `todoService` is created. The `todoService` you just updated belongs to the previous render cycle. You need to find some way of combining the functionality of the `todo` state, and the `todoService`, which is what custom hooks are for.

Comment: I just realized that I create the mock todos within the `App`. I'm so stupid. But is there a better way of forcing the state update than the flip flop thing I do?

Comment: you're also setting state inside the `useEffect` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715465/can-i-set-state-inside-a-useeffect-hook

Comment: Is that a problem? It is not clear from the question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `useEffect`in this scenario. You've put a dependency in the `useEffect` which is fine to use it to stop infinite loop. but it's unnecessary here. You're not really doing any `fetch`

You can update your code to be like this.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";

const Todo = ({ todo, completeFn }) => {
  const handleOnclick = useCallback(() => {
    // useCallback since function is passed down from parent
    console.log(`completing todo...`);
    completeFn(todo);
  }, [completeFn, todo]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name={todo.id}
        id={todo.id}
        onClick={handleOnclick}
      />
      <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor={todo.id}>
        {todo.description}
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

class TodoService {
  constructor(todos) {
    this.todos = new Map();
    todos.forEach(todo => {
      this.todos.set(todo.id, todo);
    });
  }

  findAll() {
    console.log(Array.from(this.todos.values()));
    return Array.from(this.todos.values());
  }

  saveTodo(todo) {
    this.todos[todo.id] = todo;
  }

  completeTodo(todo) {
    this.todos.delete(todo.id);
  }
}

const todoService = new TodoService([
  {
    id: 1,
    description: "Let's go home."
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    description: "Take down the trash"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    description: "Play games"
  }
]);

export default function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]); // Set initial state

  const completeTodo = todo => {
    todoService.completeTodo(todo);
    setTodos(todoService.findAll()); // Update state
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setTodos(todoService.findAll());
  }, []); // Get and update from service on first render only

  return (
    <div>
      {todos.map(todo => (
        <Todo key={todo.id} todo={todo} completeFn={completeTodo} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

working example

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-hertz-sewc5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I'm going to use Axios later, this is just a mock now.

Comment: @AdamArold I see ok... then that should be fine you can just use `[]` as your `useEffect` dependency. This will ensure that `useEffect` will run in initial render only. After that you'd want to update the state when user select complete. As shown above. that's probably the important part

Comment: I need to use `useEffect` because `todoService.findAll()` will call an API later.

Comment: updated the answer. check https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-hertz-sewc5. Also note I've used `useCallback` for `completeFn` since it's passed down from parent.