# How to get updated state in useEffect when using update loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So as you probably know, in normal mode, we use update dependencies to get notice when the state updated, like this:

```
const [val, setVal] = useState();


useEffect(() => {}, [val]]);
```

But in my case, I have an array in my state and I'm trying to update it in a loop in my useEffect like this:

```
const [val, setVal ] = useState([...]);

useEffect(() => {
   anotherArr.forEach(i => {
      // get val and modify some indexes 
      setVal(modifiedValuesArray);
   }
}, []);
```

In this case, every time forEach loop runs, I'm getting the initial val (I know because val is not a
dependency of useEffect) but if I put it as a dependency, it will update twice. what is the solution for this?

EDIT: Basically, I mean when I update state in a round of loop in useEffect, on the next round, I'm not getting the updated state but the initial state before entering the loop. And I know, that is because of the nature of useEffect which gives us a memorized value of state (since we didn't pass it as a dependency to avoid the additional execution), but what is the solution in these types of scenarios.

Comment: You should `setVal` only once. Calculate the transformed array, then set it. Is there any significant reason for using `useEffect` in that scenario specifically?

Comment: @briosheje actually the real code is much complex than this basic example. but, yeah I need to use useEffect to get notice when one of the required dependencies updates.(I want to update indexed one by one for some reasons)

Comment: @PouyaJabbarisani why not send an arrow function inside `setVal` which would have the previous state as a param ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this answer:(https://stackoverflow.com/a/59422750/2728431) and it solved my problem.

for getting updated state, (as @usafder said in a comment), we need to pass state as a value in an arrow function just like this:

```
const [val, setVal ] = useState([...]);

useEffect(() => {
   anotherArr.forEach(i => {
      setVal(val => {
         // modify based on provided val on arrow function
         return modifiedValuesArray
      });
   }

}, []);
```

Comment: Correct. There is also a library that allow you to use hook with callback. If you are interested [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-state-with-callback) npm link.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setVal` only once, not during an `forEach` loop. `setState` is `async` so you can't depend on it like its synchronous. In your example `setVal` will actually be executed some time in the future.. Do you maybe have a codesandbox example?

EDIT: You don't get updated state on "next round". `setState` will be executed N times, and will put it in an update queue, and React will probably only update the last `setState` value for optimisation. Also, your example `useEffect` will run only once..

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to update the state using its current value, you need to send in a function instead to the state setter which would give you the updated current value of the state as a param. So in your case it would be something like below:

```
const [val, setVal ] = useState([...]);

useEffect(() => {
  anotherArr.forEach(i => {
    setVal((currVal) => {
      let modifiedValuesArray = [];
      // your update logic here (use currVal instead of val)
      return modifiedValuesArray;
    });
  });
}, []);
```