# Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect using .map&useState&useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using .map inside JSX to render some components. However, the variable inside .map is updating in `useEffect`, and the dependency of `useEffect` is a `useSWR`, `useSWR` is depends on `useSearchParams()`. Is there anything I am doing wrong to trigger this error? An example:

```js
          <div>
            {koStat.map((koMatric) => 
              <div key={koMatric}>
                {koInfo[matchName]
                  ? koMatric +
                    ": " +
                    JSON.stringify(koInfo[matchName][koMatric])
                  : " unavailable"}
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
```

In here, `koInfo` is inside a `useEffect` and the dependency array of the `useEffect` is `[data, matchList]`, `data` is updating using `useSWR`, the `selectedMatch` is depends on `useSearchParams`:

```js
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const selectedMatch: string | null = searchParams.get("data")

  const { data, isLoading, error } = useSWR(
    "/api/model?data=" + selectedMatch,
    fetcher,
    {
      refreshInterval: 1000,
    }
  );
```

The complete error in the browser console:

```
app-index.js:31 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. 
This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
```

I think it probably because `one of the dependencies changes on every render.`, how can I solve it?

I have tried the solution in [Maximum update depth exceeded.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66125667/maximum-update-depth-exceeded-this-can-happen-when-a-component-calls-setstate-i), it didn't work.