# React: how to use useEffect compared to componentDidUpdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I am pretty much completely new to React. I've read the documentation and watched some YT video's. Now I am trying 'convert' some of [this React class component](https://codepen.io/techniq/pen/rLXwJJ?editors=0010) that I found online to a functional component. This is how far I've come: [My functional component(codesandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-flower-dy2u1?file=/src/App.js).

It is a component to automatically wrap SVG text using `tspan` elements based on a user input field.

I am specifically having a hard time with the useEffect hook. As I understand it, it should function as the equivelant of `componentWillMount` and `componentDidUpdate`. Now I've got everything pretty much setup, but it does not yet update the `Text` component whenever new text is added in the textarea. I believe this is because I have to do something in the `useEffect` hook in the `Text` component:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    //something so that lines get updated if the user input changes?
  }, [lines]);
```

The things I've tried resulted in an infinite loop. See: [Can I use set state inside a useEffect hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715465/can-i-set-state-inside-a-useeffect-hook).

Could someone point me in the right direction? Feel free to fork the codesandbox :)

Comment: Could you attach a link to your code one more time? There are dummy data now

Comment: @Pasha Here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-flower-dy2u1?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, useEffect is not like componentWillMount, it's componentDidMount - effects fire **after** a render.

Secondly, in your specific example, what you want is to fire an effect when **dummyText** updates so it can recalculate lines.

In order to do that, your effect looks like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    //something so that lines get updated if the user input changes?
  }, [dummyText]);
```

Thirdly, and most importantly, you shouldn't do that either because `lines` is *not actually state* of your `Text` component - it's just a computed value based on the `dummyText` prop. state is something your component owns, something it has created. Your `Text` component didn't create lines, it just calculated them based on the `dummyText` prop.

Comment: Allright, understood. What do you recommend me to do to achieve my desired result? Move the logic to the `Content` component because dummyText is state of that component?

Comment: @Reinier68 - exactly.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Text` component your `useEffect` function doesn't track the `dummyText` prop. Try to add it into dependency array, like this (Text.jsx, line 60):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const { wordsWithComputedWidth, spaceWidth } = calculateWordWidths();
    const lines2 = calculateLines(wordsWithComputedWidth, spaceWidth, 400);
    setLines(lines2);
  }, [dummyText]);
```