# UseState doesn't update in componentDidMount lifecycle method

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Recently I am practicing my react skill and trying to build an easy component, and I fall into a confusing situation.

Here is the code, I am wondering why my react page doesn't render the data after I unshift it(should render Select All option), I do some research about it and I know the issue is closure([useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)), but I am still confusing if it is the case, when it goto useEffect, it's closure is the original data and I unshift it, then setState should update the data after.

I know I can fix it by creating a temporary variable in useEffect and setState with it but I am still wondering how it work and what happen behind the scene.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const selections = ["Kosher", "No Celery(inc celeriac)", "No Egg"];
const dataConfig = selections.map((selection) => ({
  value: selection,
  isSelect: false
}));

const Selector = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(dataConfig);

  useEffect(() => {
    data.unshift({
      value: "Select All",
      isSelect: false
    });
    setData(data);
  }, []);



  return (
    <div className="container">
      {console.log(data)}
      {data.map((ele, idx) => {
        return (
          <div key={Math.random()}>
            <input type="checkbox" value={ele.value} />
            <label>{ele.value}</label>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Selector;
```

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715465/can-i-set-state-inside-a-useeffect-hook
Try `setData(state => ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Array.prototype.unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) mutates the array in-place. React doesn't detect that your state has changed because the object reference is the same.

See [Bailing out of a state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update)

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects. (React uses the [`Object.is` comparison algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#Description).)

Try this instead which creates a new array, thus triggering a state change

```js
setData(prev => [{
  value: "Select All",
  isSelected: false,
}, ...prev]);
```

Comment: A smaller change to @faithans existing code is to simply replace `setData(data)` with `setData([...data])`. Nevertheless @Phil's explanation was great.

Comment: @NguyễnVũKhang I always feel like it's wrong to directly mutate the state variables, if only to prevent accidentally doing something like in the question