# React Hook useState Is Returning Undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to fill a table with data from an API.

UPDATED*************

```
import React, { useMemo, useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";

import {
  AppLayout,
  Button,
  Box,
  Form,
  SpaceBetween,
  Grid,
} from "@affn/awsui-components-react/polaris";
import "@affn/awsui-global-styles/polaris.css";
import "./styles/landing-page.scss";
import { appLayoutLabels, externalLinkProps } from "./common/labels";
import Picture1 from "./resources/engineLogos/bric_team_dark_backgroung(1).svg";
import {
  ExternalLinkItem,
  Navigation,
  InfoLink,
} from "./commons/common-components-BRIC";

function BricPage() {
  
  const Content = ({ navigationOpen }) => {
    //Constants needed by the form ------------------------------------------------
    
    const refreshPage = () => {
      window.location.reload();
    };

    // The comment (i.e conversation) id must be unique
    const conversationId = uuidv4();

    //Function to handle submit click and create SIM
    const handleClick = (
      title1,
      description1,
    ) => () => {
      console.log(title1);
      console.log(description1);

    };

    const [GetSimIDs, setGetSimIDs] = React.useState([]); //Which is the impacted region?

  // Using useEffect to call the API once mounted and set the data
  useEffect(() => {
    window.harxny.api
      .invokeProxy(
        "/sit/ises?sort=createDate desc&q=status:(Open) containingFolder:(45-b5b9-4829-8b87-489053f9bb42)",
        {
          method: "GET",
          // SIM integration is only possible from the 'beta' and 'corp' stages.
          stage: "corp",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      ) //api finishes here
      .then((xhr) => {
        //response is captured here
        //var SIMID = JSON.parse(xhr.response).id;
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        const data = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
        //const data = xhr.response;
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.totalNumberFound);
        setGetSimIDs(data);
        console.log(GetSimIDs);
      });
  }, []);


    //End of Constants -------------------------------------------------------------
    console.log(GetSimIDs);
    return (
      <Box margin={{ bottom: "l" }}>
      
        <div className="center-form">
          <Box>
            <Grid
              gridDefinition={[
                {
                  colspan: { xl: "2", l: "2", s: "5", xxs: "10" },
                  offset: { l: "2", xxs: "1" },
                },
                {
                  colspan: { xl: "2", l: "3", s: "5", xxs: "10" },
                  offset: { s: "0", xxs: "1" },
                },
              ]}
            >
              <div className="custom-home-main-content-area">
                <SpaceBetween size="l">
                  <Form
                    actions={
                      <SpaceBetween direction="horizontal" size="xs">
                        <Button onClick={refreshPage} variant="link">
                          Reset Form
                        </Button>

                        <Button
                          variant="primary"
                          onClick={handleClick(
                            title1,
                            description1,
                          )}
                          ariaLabel="Submit"
                        >
                          Submit
                        </Button>
                      </SpaceBetween>
                    }
                  >
                  </Form>
                </SpaceBetween>
              </div>

            {/* Table goes here */}

            {console.log(GetSimIDs)}


              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th>title</th>
                  <th>Id</th>
                </tr>
                {GetSimIDs.documents.map((item, i) => (
                  <tr key={i}>
                    <td>{item.title}</td>
                    <td>{item.id}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </Grid>
          </Box>
        </div>
      </Box>
    );
  };

  const [navigationOpen, setNavigationOpen] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <AppLayout
      disableContentPaddings={true}
      content={<Content />}
      navigation={<Navigation activeHref="#/" />}
      navigationOpen={navigationOpen}
      onNavigationChange={({ detail }) => setNavigationOpen(detail.open)}
      toolsHide={true}
      ariaLabels={appLayoutLabels}
    />
  );
}

export default BricPage;
```

The state `GetSimIDs` is updated successfully with data like this:

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "assignedFolder": "4a37-416c-8531-",
      "extensions": {
        "tt": {
          "impact": 5,
          "category": "EiC",
          "type": "IBug",
          "item": "Macro",
          "assignedGroup": "EiC",
          "justification": [],
          "minImpact": 5,
          "status": "Assd"
        }
      },
      "watchers": [
        { "id": "bric-primary@amazon.com", "type": "email" },
        { "id": "sssesuni@amazon.com", "type": "email" },
        { "id": "raaishwa@amazon.com", "type": "email" },
        { "id": "dipchakr@amazon.com", "type": "email" }
      ],
      "customFields": {
        "number": [{ "id": "fte_saving", "value": 0 }],
        "date": [
          { "id": "delivery_date", "value": "2022-05-17T15:43:49.825Z" }
        ],
        "string": [
          { "id": "category_of_the_request", "value": "Other" },
          { "id": "region_of_impact", "value": "NA" },
          { "id": "tool_type", "value": "Excel Macro" },
          {
            "id": "impacted_tool",
            "value": "Tickets Helper"
          }
        ]
      }
     
    },
    {
      "title": "Issue or Bug - Global Wizard - NA",
      "assignedFolder": "416c-8531-37fa3a701712",
      
      "watchers": [{ "id": "bprimary@a.com", "type": "email" }],
      "customFields": {
        "number": [{ "id": "fte_saving", "value": 0 }],
        "date": [
          { "id": "delivery_date", "value": "2022-05-13T02:22:46.751Z" }
        ],
        "string": [
          { "id": "category_of_the_request", "value": "Other" },
          { "id": "region_of_impact", "value": "NA" },
          { "id": "tool_type", "value": "Excel Macro" },
          { "id": "impacted_tool", "value": "Global Wizard" }
        ]
      }
      
    }
  ],
  "totalNumberFound": 2,
  "searchLogMessages": [],
  "startToken": ""
}
```

So I tried to update the table with the following code:

```
<tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th>title</th>
                  <th>Id</th>
                  <th>status</th>
                </tr>
                {GetSimIDs.map((documents, i) => (
                  <tr key={i}>
                    <td>{documents.title}</td>
                    <td>{documents.id}</td>
                    <td>{documents.status}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
```

But I keep getting an error in line

```
{GetSimIDs.map((documents, i) => (
```

Saying that `TypeError: s is undefined`

Any idea as of why it seems not getting the data from the hook?

I am very new to react so all feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks
Luis V.

Comment: You are trying to set GetSimIDs with all your JSON object. Maybe set only the value you need sth like `data.documents`. Also note that your json file does not seem to contain any `id` or `status`. Are you sure `GetSimIDs` contain those values? And note that some entries in the json file do not contain `title` Maybe to check if a property exist or not. If you are using typescript you can use `documents?.title`. As a side suggestion I would not use `.map` if I am not changing the values inside the GetSimIDs. Instead I would use `forEach`

Comment: Due to NDAs I can not share the exact json sorry but yes it includes id and status. I tried data.documents and no luck :( I will try a forEach maybe because the error keeps saying that  the line "GetSimIDs.documents.map((item, i) => ( "  is undefiend ...

Comment: Maybe a binding error? Try es6 function to bind to this?

Comment: `GetSimIDs` has an undefined initial state value, so trying to access into it on the initial render throws this error. See Brian Thompson's answer below.

Comment: Maybe also you don't need to call it React.useState just useState([]) as you already import it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can log the value of GetSimIDs and GetSimIDs before the `map` function.

```
console.log(GetSimIDs, GetSimIDs.documents)
GetSimIDs.map...
```

It will probably be `undefined` as at the first load of the page it is not initialized.

I would suggest you set the `const [GetSimIDs, setGetSimIDs] = React.useState([]);` instead of empty.

For your further problem with react hooks (useEffect) I would suggest you `setState` outside the `useEffect`. Extract the method that fetches data e.g `getData` and then use it inside `useEffect()`

```
useEffect(()=>{getData()},[])
```

Comment: You are right, for some reason it is not saving the info in the state const [GetSimIDs, setGetSimIDs] = React.useState([]);

Comment: I have updated the code in the question, I am not sure if I am usin the useEffect in the right place to be honest because when I print in the return() the array is blank

Comment: A quick fix would be to just check before the `map` {GetSimIDs && GetSimIDs.documents &$ GetSimIDs.map(...

Comment: @luisvv93 maybe put the `GetSimIDs` inside the useEffect at the end of the `use effect`. From `}, []);` to `}, [GetSimIDs]);`

Comment: It is working with that suggestion @besjon_c , thank you, now it keeps printing the info in the console , is that the right behavior?

Comment: Yes because it is renderin multiple times and it is updating the GetSimIDs every time. I would suggest you extract your method that fetch data from `useEffect`. Create another function `getData`. So the `setState` would be outside of useEffect and then in useEffect just call that method only once. `useEffect(()=>{getData()},[])`. btw the reason why it renders multiple times it is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715465/can-i-set-state-inside-a-useeffect-hook.

Answer (score 4):

This is a common problem with async data. The state is initially undefined, and is filled in later after the request has completed. There will **always** be at least one render before your data is loaded.

You can fix this in several ways, but the simplest would be to just initialize the state to an empty array:

```
const [GetSimIDs, setGetSimIDs] = React.useState([]);
```

Now the state is always defined, and you can map over it even before the data is loaded.

Another option would be to check the data before mapping it:

```
{GetSimIDs && GetSimIDs.map((documents, i) => (
```

Answer (score 2):

Data returned from the API seems to be an `object` with a property `documents` which is an `array`. Either you can

```
setGetSimIDs(data.documents)
```

OR

```
GetSimIDs.documents.map(...)
```

**Update** ([Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-sanne-4cw5wc?file=/src/App.js)): Seems you're also missing a few null checks due to which there are errors. Initially the object + array are empty so we can't use the map function. Only when data has **successfully** loaded we can render the rows.

I have used your data set & made a [mock api](https://getsimids.free.beeceptor.com/my/api/path).

```
export default function App() {
  const [GetSimIDs, setGetSimIDs] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://getsimids.free.beeceptor.com/my/api/path")
      .then((res) => {
        setGetSimIDs(res.data);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>status</th>
          </tr>
          {GetSimIDs.documents &&
            GetSimIDs.documents.length > 0 &&
            GetSimIDs.documents.map((documents, i) => (
              <tr key={i}>
                <td>{documents.title}</td>
                <td>{documents.id}</td>
                <td>{documents.status}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried both but the same error persists :(

Comment: @luisvv93 Pls see update. I've made a codesandbox which you can review.

Comment: Thank you very much @Aseem Gautam i just replicated what you did and I am still not getting anything, but I think it is because I have included it in the wrong place, I am going to update the main questions so that you can see it

Comment: I have updated the code in the question, I am not sure if I am usin the useEffect in the right place to be honest because when I print in the return() the array is blank