# Is it possible to call hooks inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I wrote this code

```
    const [word, setWord] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener("keypress", handleClick);
    });
    function handleClick(e) {
        if (word.length < 5){
            setWord([
                ...word,
                e.key
            ])
        }
    }
```

But now I doubt whether this is correct from the point of view of react. After all, it seems that it is impossible to call hooks inside other hooks.

Comment: This isn't setting state inside an effect, all that happens in the effect is the event listener is added to the document. But in answer to the question in the title: [Can I set state inside a useEffect hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715465/can-i-set-state-inside-a-useeffect-hook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've shared does not call hooks inside other hooks directly, so you're fine in that aspect.

Here's the revised code of your React component:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function YourComponent() {
    const [word, setWord] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener("keypress", handleClick);

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("keypress", handleClick);
        };
    }, []);

    function handleClick(e) {
        if (word.length < 5) {
            setWord(prevWord => [...prevWord, e.key]);
        }
    }

    // other parts of the code (component)
}

export default YourComponent;
```

Remove event listeners from the DOM when the component unmounts to avoid memory leaks. Use an empty dependency array in `useEffect` for one-time effects, and apply functional updates when setting state based on the previous state.